# What action should be taken on very basic programming question?

Tags: discussion, support, triage

While reviewing posts, I stuck some time on what to do when I see very basic programming question. The question is not duplicate or may be I do not want to put efforts to find StackOverflow whether it is duplicate. The question is real question. Enough data is also provided. Question is answerable and all ok. The only problem I find in question is that, it is very basic; that is why whether it is duplicate or not does not matter.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240480/javascript-filter-html-table-with-input-text-and-select-iption). This question could be answered. But the question is very basic. How to filter HTML table? Just search net and you should get tons of code there.

I left the comment, but the user is new user. It could not be guaranteed that he will come back and will edit/delete question.

I am in "Review|Triage", so cannot down vote because that button is not available. Also, just down voting does not fix the concern.

If I am understanding StackOverflow correctly, this question should be marked for delete/close. So I go to `Flag` and try to find suitable reason to close/delete the question. But it is not listed in options.

What should I do in such case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay.  Here's the thing.

**It's not a bad thing to ask a beginner question.**  It just has to be one that fits within the site's guidelines.

This means:

- It has to be well-scoped,
- clear,
- have the necessary code that produces an issue if code is warranted, and
- have a objective definition of "correct".

The question you pose states this (sans code):

> Good Day Everyone
>
> i'm use in making javascripts and jquery, can you help me on how to
>   create table filtering using a textbox and a select option list.
>
> can someone give me a simple filtering in javascript or jquery?
>
> thanks and regards everyone.

If you didn't see any code with a question like that, you'd have voted to close it as Too Broad before you even finished reading the salutation.

**And that's what you should do here.**  Flag this as Unsalvagable (or flag this to be closed "Too Broad"), whichever is applicable in your queue.   The question is asking too much of us.