# What action should be taken on question that does not make sense?

Tags: discussion, support

I came across a question that does not make sense. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42358046/5779732).

> **How to return a DataSet from Dapper [on hold]**
>   I'm using dapper in my ASP.NET MVC project. Now I'd like to get the
>   results in a DataSet. How can I achieve this?
>
> I have tried to used the QueryMultiple function, but couldn't get it
>   to work.
>   **Tags: .net, dataset, dapper**

ORMs used to access database in OO way. The OP want to convert that OO output back to classic DataSet. This could be easily done using basic ADO.NET code that is widely available on net. Apart from that, if all OP want is the DataSet, then why ORM?

I left the comment, but the OP never replied. It could not be guaranteed that he will come back and will edit/delete the question.

I down-voted but I thought this question should be marked for delete. So I flagged it "Unclear what you are asking". I am not sure if this is correct reason because it is well clear to me what he is asking. It is just that what he is asking does not make sense; and that is because OP does not have enough understanding of ORMs. I cannot teach him ORMs in one answer.

What is the correct flag for this case?
Shouldn't we have flag something like "homework not done"? This also covers my [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343851/5779732) question.

Comment: If it doesn't make any sense then the "unclear" close reason fits well. If you say the question is understandable but would require a long explanation on the underlying technologies - because the OP hasn't understood them yet -before you could even answer the question itself, then the question is likely too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What action should be taken on question that does not make sense?

If you can't make sense of the question you ask for clarification and flag/vote to close as unclear. That's the only things you can do.

Comment: I already asked for clarification but the OP does not show up again. I also down-voted; but I thought better approach is to flag the question for deletion and I did so. Its just that the reason I gave for deletion is not the best reason.

Comment: @A_J actually, all actions has to be done at the same time: you ask for clarification and flag to close. that way if OP bails out, the question willl be closed and delete, if it doesn't then we could simply stop the process short.