# New Flag to delete the question asked without any efforts

Tags: feature-request, questions, flags, vote-to-delete

A new flag should be provided to delete the question asked without any efforts. Flag might be **"No Self-Efforts Taken"** or anything similar.

There are many questions without self-effort on Stack Overflow being posted daily. Today, I came across this [Sorting in SQL Server by two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43992830/5779732). Notice that: -

- The question is upvoted
- Question have answers
- Question is edited by very high reputation user

Also note that: -

- This is no spam. Language is polite; its not abusive.
- Question is good and on topic.
- Question is clear.
- Enough inputs are provided to answer the question. This could be answered.
- It was not formatted at all; but now it is very well formatted.
- Question is neither broad nor opinion based.
- I do not want to put efforts finding if this is duplicate question; because I can clearly see OP have not put any efforts before asking. Also, searching Google is more quick and easy for OP than searching duplicate on Stack Overflow for us.

Above list wipes out all the flags available to close/delete the question.

The only problem with the question is that, there are no efforts put by OP. OP does not post any code that he tried. Even though he do, that does not change the fact. The question is about very basic and widely used **syntax** of SQL.

Simple search on internet could easily fix this. In-fact, paying enough attention in classroom is better than internet search. This is a lesson generally taught on first day of SQL training. If someone is asking this question have definitely put zero efforts to fix the problem or to find the solution. **Or if I decide to be more specific, this is not a problem at all.** This just means, OP do not know even basics of technology he is attempting to use.

## Objective of Stack Overflow

In my understanding (correct me if I am wrong), objective is to provide a platform for developers to post problems and get solutions. Asking such zero effort questions does not serve the objective. Actually, it works against it.

IMHO site does not provide "technology training/learning" service.

Will it be acceptable if someone ask a question "What is the syntax of for loop in C#?" in such a way that it ticks all the boxes and not a duplicate? If **NO**, then question above is same case. If **YES**, then Stack Overflow is actually providing "training services".

I read at multiple locations on meta that OP must have basic understanding of technology he is attempting to use. But Stack Overflow do not provide a way to convey this to OP; the flag that I am talking about.

## It's not a bad thing to ask a beginner question

I raised the question ([What action should be taken on very basic programming question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343851/5779732)) earlier about this. @Makoto said, "It's not a bad thing to ask a beginner question". Even though, OP does not post any code, this is not "Too Broad". I have already mentioned above that none of existing flags explains the reason for deletion clearly.

## Reputation Race

Asking and answering such question will promote reputation race. I was the first (or may be second) one who viewed this question. Instead of commenting, one can make his mind to answer it instead. There are lot of chances to get up-votes and the answer being accepted because the tag and technology is popular.

Comment: Presumably that would be grounds to close this question itself as there is no sign of any research effort here, i.e. the history of lacks minimal understanding, other questions/answers on this topic on meta etc.

Comment: The question ticks so many boxes and yet you want a flag for speedy deletion just because you think it's "Very Basic"? Really?

Comment: lack of research generally means downvoting..

Comment: Downvote if you think it's not useful or lacks research i.e. searching for whether it's already asked here, or close as a duplicate if you can find a duplicate.

Comment: I'm genuinely concerned that my message was missed or misinterpreted by you.  There's really nothing wrong with the question you've linked.  It ticks off *so* many boxes as @BoltClock said.  So what if it's a bit basic?  If you don't want to answer it, ain't no one gonna force you, but you can't deride the question ***just because it's basic to you***.

Comment: @Rob you're right there's nothing wrong with a basic question, however there is something wrong with a question who's title can be googled to get an answer, though not so bad that it needs deleting right away thanks to it's own flag, just downvote and if it's score gets < 0 let the Roomba deal with it

Comment: No, I don't see much, if any research effort undertaken by you in asking this question, but the irony seems lost on you.

Comment: Thanks, but you really didn't have to repeat that three times.

Comment: Well no, let's not take that away; that was your phrasing.  My particular answer didn't mention anything about "effort" per se.  I won't deny that a question which is nothing more than a glorified "do my work for me please" isn't reasonable here, but it isn't like this question is particularly *bad*, either.  If the only reason you're giving us to remove it is that "it's basic", then it's best to leave it where you found it.

Comment: The term "basic" itself is vague. For person X "breaking immutability of Strings" could be "basic" but for person "Y" its ""really advanced". Your question is based on a false assumption that "everybody assumes the same thing about a particular question"

Comment: @Memor-X If it can be googled and get an answer, then close it as a duplicate if that answer is on stack overflow. If it's not, then it's fine.

Comment: I have edited my question much. I removed the term "basic" from all over. I agree it created more trouble and I also agree asking basic question should be welcome and that "basic" or not decision may change per person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I detest "do my work for me" questions as much as the next guy, and I can see a case for deleting questions where the user simply isn't even interested in making their question *belong* on the site, like questions that consist of a single link to a photo of a *handwritten question* — and moderators speed-delete garbage posts all the time — but that seems irrelevant to you, judging by your statement,

> Even though he do *[sic]*, that does not change the fact that the question is very basic.

So, considering that you yourself state that this question otherwise ticks all the boxes ("Question is clear" and "neither broad nor opinion based"! What more could you ask for?!), why do you feel that the question is grounds for speedy deletion just because it's "Very Basic"? Why must such a question go away as quickly as possible? What about it makes it extremely harmful to the site, and not harmless as it seems to be to everyone else?

> I do not want to put efforts finding if this is duplicate question; because this is very basic.

If the reason you want a "speedy deletion" flag is simply because you can't be bothered to moderate the question for what it is (a duplicate, perhaps, as you seem to imply), then *don't moderate*. Although every user is given moderation privileges as they earn reputation on the site, no one is obligated to exercise them. If you don't think a question is worth your time (let's ignore the fact that you took the time to leave comments on the question pointing the asker in the right direction for a minute), no one's making you spend time on it. Find something else that's more worthwhile.

If you think inaction makes you part of the problem, well, you're not really helping matters here. Just asking for questions to be deleted willy-nilly when they're not actively harming the integrity of the site (like spam or abusive content does) runs counter to the spirit of Stack Overflow. We'd rather you just did nothing in that case.